# Adding BottomAppBar programatically in C# with a button

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I want to add BottomAppBar programatically from code-behind in C#. I got it done like this:

1: Added a resource file that has DataTemplate which contains a Grid, a StackPanel and two buttons.

2: In my BasePage.cs (that derives from the Page class) I define a new AppBar and set it's ContentTemplate to the Resource created in step1.

3: I set this.BottomAppBar= AppBar from step2.

Now this add the AppBar to all my pages that are derived from BasePage. This works fine.

The issue:

I cannot get the PointerPressed or any other events fired from my two elements in AppBar.

I am sure it's something very basic I am missing. Any ideas, anyone?

**Update:** Sample download link added below and what I would like is when the image in the BottomAppBar (Page1 and 2)is clicked, it should take me to MainPage.

[Download Sample](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=F0F619FD01FE8C33!274)

**AppBar Code**

```
AppBar appbar = new AppBar();
appbar.Name = "BottomBar";
DataTemplate dt = Application.Current.Resources["BottomAppBarDT"] as DataTemplate;
appbar.ContentTemplate = dt;
this.BottomAppBar = appbar;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Data Templating its always best to implement Commands instead of Event Handlers. 
What you will want to do is make sure that you create a DelegateCommand that has the same methodology as the Button Click Event you are attempting to trigger.
The code for the DelegateCommand should be placed in the View Model that serves as the DataContext for the parent of this particular control (App Bar) or If you're using an MVVM structure that has a Command Aggregator it should go in there.

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
  {
    private Action _action;

    public DelegateCommand(Action action)
    {
      _action = action;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
      return true;
    }

    public event Windows.UI.Xaml.EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;


    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
      _action();
    }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Gets a command that executes a search
  /// </summary>
  public ICommand ExecuteSearchCommand
  {
    get
    {
      return new DelegateCommand(() => ExecuteSearch());
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Zack. No I am not using MVVM as of now but would like to if it fits my app. I will try out your suggestion and look more into MVVM.

Comment: I got it working with your idea and the code article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/391783/An-Address-Book-Application-Made-in-MVVM-For-Metro. I will upload my code. Although I got it working on a button, I would also like this to work on an Image PointerPressed. Image doesn't support Command.

Comment: You could use a button and create a template, and Im sure there is probably one online for something called "ImageButton" ... this was the first result I found on Google. http://www.michielpost.nl/PostDetail_72.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually added `Click` event handler to the buttons on the `AppBar`?

Comment: Yes I did. But that won't work. If I add the appbar to the xaml manually and bring the click handler to the code-behind of the page, it works. But in that case I need to do that to all my pages.

Comment: Sure...I will have to create a sample Page to demonstrate it...later today.

Comment: I added the link to a sample project describing my issue.

Comment: @TrekStir I don't see any event handler or even a button in your `AppBar` code. am I missing something?

Comment: Yes I tried adding it in different ways but none worked and so in the sample I removed it. Hoping someone can give me a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final code.

**BaseView.cs**

```
public partial class BaseView: Page
    {
        public BaseView()
        {
            GoHomeCommand = new MyCommand<object>(OnGoHome);
            this.DataContext = this;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.  The Parameter
        /// property is typically used to configure the page.</param>
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            AddAppBar();
        }
        private void AddAppBar()
        {
            AppBar appbar = new AppBar();
            appbar.Name = "BottomBar";
            DataTemplate dt = Application.Current.Resources["BottomAppBarDT"] as DataTemplate;
            appbar.ContentTemplate = dt;
            this.BottomAppBar = appbar;
        }

        public MyCommand<object> GoHomeCommand { get; set; }
        void OnGoHome(object obj)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Go Home2");
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
        }
    }

    public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
    {
        private Action _action;

        public DelegateCommand(Action action)
        {
            _action = action;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _action();
        }
    }
```

**Resource**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="BottomAppBarDT" >
        <Grid x:Name="AppBarGrid" Background="SlateGray">
            <StackPanel x:Name="AppBarRightStack" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Button Command="{Binding GoHomeCommand}" FontSize="24">
                    <Image Source="Assets/Logo.png" Height="100" Width="100"/>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```